# Un-named parameter in function definition

Tags: c++

I understand that function prototypes don't need to have a name associated with the parameters.  For example:

```
void foo(int, std::string);
```

I was interested to find out recently that you could do the same thing in a function definition though:

```
void* foo(void*) { std::cerr << "Hello World!" << std::endl; }
```

Why does this work and how could you ever make use of an un-named parameter?  Is there a reason this is allowed (like maybe dealing with legacy interfaces or something along those lines)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't intend to use the argument, then this is a good way of preventing compilers from warning you about it.

This does indeed come up most often in the context of satisfying interfaces.  For instance. you may be overriding a base-class method, but have no use for the parameters.

Comment: Or the implementation changed and the argument is no longer needed, but you don't want to break ABI/old clients.

Comment: Another common situation is callbacks and/or function pointers.